# Sending Control-N and <CR><LF> via telnet using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, terminal, ascii, telnet

I am currently using minimalistic Telnet from CodeProject and am having trouble sending the correct output to my telnet device. Essentially I am trying to automate the gathering of config data from Netopia DSL modems using this process. I am able to read the welcome screen of the netopia telnet interface just fine however I can not get any further.

The process manually goes like this: 
1) Telnet to device ip
2) A welcome screen is displayed.
3) While on the welcome screen, press Control-N
4) Presented with a # prompt
5) sh config  would print the config file to the screen.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are ascii codes.

```
char ctrln = (char)0x0E;
char cr = '\r';
char lf = '\n';
```

I've not tested the ctrl+n one but the other two should work.

Comment: That worked perfectly ("char ctrln = (char)0x0E;
"), thank you! The way I implemented it in my code was:"string strCtrln = Convert.ToString(ctrln); telnetComponent.Write(strCtrln + Environment.NewLine); I also wanted to ask, how did you know that Ctrl-N is 0x0E? Is there a way I can look these up myself in the future?

Comment: I googled ASCII CTRL+N and it gave me this link: http://www.bbdsoft.com/ascii.html. Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var login = "Login"+Environment.NewLine; // add carriage return at the end of text
var password = "Password" +Environment.NewLine;
telnetComponent.Send(login);
telnetComponent.Send(password);
```