# Sending shift+f10 over a terminal

Tags: c#, terminal, sequence, shift

I made a simple application to connect to an application via terminal. I used an external library I found on the internet (can't recall where exactly). The code works something like this:

```
Telnet t = new Telnet("127.0.0.1", 23, 100);
if (!t.Connect())
    return;

t.SendAndWait("?", "> ");
Console.WriteLine(t.lastResponse);
```

Which sends `?` to console and waits for `>`. However, I need to send <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> sometimes (it's *break* command for application), and I don't know how to do this. After some research I found out that I may need to send something like this:

```
t.SendAndWait("^[1~", "> ");
```

*^[* would be escape character, and *1~* I found out using telnet in windows, connecting to same application and pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>. But I can't figure out what code would be equivalent to <kbd>shift</kbd>, nor if this is correct approach at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindof workaround - thanks to answer [Sending Control-N and <CR><LF> via telnet using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022005/sending-control-n-and-crlf-via-telnet-using-c-sharp) and mentioned page http://www.bbdsoft.com/ascii.html, I figured out I can use CTRL+Y as well to interrupt, and the following code works okay:

```
t.SendAndWait(Char.ToString((char)0x19), "< ");
```